# Android How to configure emulator for simulating no phone call support

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to configure emulator for simulating no phone call functionality support. In order to test my application to check, how application will behave if device doesn't support call functionality.

I had look into AVD hardware property's [here](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4ccok) , but i don't find any property related to call.

Is it possible to test this scenario on emulator or only possible on real device?

Edit 1: Tried

- "GSM modem support" set to "no" its disabled network.
- Airplane mode ON/OFF.
- Tablet emulator.

> ```
> TelephonyManager telephonyManager1 = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>
> if(telephonyManager1.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE)
>   System.out.println("No Phone Functionality");       
> else 
>   System.out.println("Phone Functionality");
> ```

It always goes into else part and the Phone type value is PHONE_TYPE_GSM in all cases

Comment: @RiNxX-Sarim tried din't help.

Comment: it could be possible that this will not work in emulator, because not everything is properly mapped to the goldfish kernel. check the emulator doc for the features that are not supported

Comment: @amsiddh did u find any solution to check this condition in simulator ?

Answer (score 2):

"GSM modem support" set to "no"

I tested it and with this flag it acts as a device without mobile network.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. yup your right even i was trying, no network if "GSM modem support" set to "no"

Comment: this turns off all data connections though. I want WiFi but no phone support. Is this possible in emulator?